# Document (almost) empty after being renamed

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I was editing a document. I closed it. Renamed it. Reopened it and all the content is gone, except the footer. I tried to open it using Google Docs and I can see the 11 pages that I had: the charts, tables but no text.

What should I do to retrieve my content?

Comment: have you tried removing the formatting? (select all the text body first)

Comment: Yes, I didn't work. I was pressed by time so I started my document over but I am still interested in knowing how I could retrieve all the content.

Comment: Rename it back. Make backup copies first, then play around. Also try to repeat this failure with your new doc. (Backup!). I would also open it in OpenOffice to see whether the content still exists.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasKnauss for getting back to me! Unfortunately, I already tried all of that. Renaming it didn't change anything. I tried to repeat the failure with my new document and it didn't happen. I also opened in in OpenOffice but only the charts and the tables showed up but no text - just like in Google Docs. I don't get it.

Comment: Hope it was a one time failure. Remember to backup your files in the future. ;-)

Comment: You're right! :) I started to switch all my reports to revision control.